# Filtering DataGridView using Comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, filtering

Let me preface this by saying I am a beginner as far as .net knowledge.

I am developing a windows form application using tabs in VS2012 in vb. I have bound the datagrid through the designer to a sql server binding source which is populating the data. There are multiple columns in the table and these are split between two tabs with a datagrid on each tab. Both data grids have the same binding source just show different columns.

I created a view within the SQL server to pull in the column names. I think what I want to do and not sure if this is possible but have 2 combo boxes that will be used to filter. One of the would be bound to the view by a dataadapter and then the second to the datagrid binding source.

when the user selects the first combobox(columnname) it would then pull from the datagrid for that column and pull in the valid values to filter. It would then filter the datagridview and refresh it.

Then I am trying to remove the filters through the use of a button.

Can someone please help as I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dataview in filtering datasources. You can refer to my answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593378/how-to-fill-a-combobox-based-on-other-combobox)